# CSS Navbar - How to evenly space out elements

Tags: html, css

The spaces in the navbar elements at the center is not equal. CSS also seems to let text overlap with other elements for example if I write "HOMEabcdefgh" it will overlap with the next element instead of spacing it out evenly.

Also HOME text is shorter than the rest of the elements text hence we see a lot of spacing between it and its next element "DRESSES". I want to evenly space out all the center elements. Please see the image
[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #b7b7b7;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  background-color: #332323;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
}

.nav_links a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  min-width: 80px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #302b2b;
  padding: 5px 10%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h4 class="logo">N</h4>
  <nav class='nav1'>
    <ul class='nav_links'>
      <a>
        <li href="#home">Home</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li href="#dresses">Dresses</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li href="#trends">Trends</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a href="#"><button class="button">Contact</button></a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the Nav some width and then use flex box on the nav_links.
I removed all you'r padding anchor width and margin

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #b7b7b7;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10%;
    background-color: #332323;
  }
  
  .logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
  }
   /** Give the nav a width */
  .nav1{
      width:20%;
  }
  /** Set the flex properties */
  .nav_links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nav_links a {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  .button {
    background-color: #302b2b;
    padding: 5px 10%;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the ul display:flex with space between

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #b7b7b7;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  background-color: #332323;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
}

.nav_links a {
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #302b2b;
  padding: 5px 10%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h4 class="logo">N</h4>
  <nav class='nav1'>
    <ul class='nav_links'>
      <a>
        <li href="#home">Home</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li href="#dresses">Dresses</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li href="#trends">Trends</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a href="#"><button class="button">Contact</button></a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner flexbox on the nav. Also, you have hrefs on `<li>` elements, which isn't needed. You can add links directly to the `<nav>` and it will align them as needed, since it itself is also within a flexbox, spaced evenly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #b7b7b7;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  background-color: #332323;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav a {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: #302b2b;
  padding: 5px 10%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h4 class="logo">N</h4>
  <nav class='nav1'>
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#dresses">Dresses</a>
    <a href="#trends">Trends</a>
  </nav>
  <a href="#"><button class="button">Contact</button></a>
</header>
```